# How to run a SPARQL update statement using RDFLIB in python

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I know there is an update statement in SPARQL, but I am not really sure how to use it in RDFLIB. For instance, I have an ontology that contains Alice      and Julius as individuals and I want to run a SPARQL update to change their properties. This includes things like updating their ages, likes, hobbies, etc.

I also want to be able to add individuals and their properties if they do not exist in the ontology. Example, adding John, his age, likes, hobbies, etc.

Comment: as stated in the [documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html), instead of calling `g.query(queryString)` on a graph `g` you call `g.update(updateCommandString)` - anything else unclear?

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser, I will try this and see what comes. Hopefully it solve the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: do the examples help? E.g., [sparql_update_example.py](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/examples/sparql_update_example.py)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm just adding UninformedUser's comment here in a response so this can be accepted.*

You do just use `g.update(queryString)`, see the documentation here:

https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_to_sparql.html#update-queries